# SmartBoard 680 repeatedly disconnects when sound is played through speakers

Tags: windows-7, usb, speakers

We recently changed out a computer from Windows XP to Windows 7.  I installed the SmartBoard drivers, made sure we connected to the SmartBoard just fine, and then tested it.  After each button press that made a sound go through the SmartBoard speakers, the SmartBoard disconnects and goes through the Windows hardware discovery again.  It took me a while to narrow it down to this, but I confirmed it by playing sound through a different set of speakers and I didn't have the problem.

This is connected through a USB extension.  I have reseated the USB and cat5 connections on the extenders, moved to a different USB port, updated the firmware and drivers, uninstalled the drivers from the new computer and installed the old drivers, and connected the SmartBoard through a powered USB hub.  I searched around online, but SmartTech doesn't have a troubleshooting guide that even comes close to this, and none of the forum posts I could find seemed relevant.

Answer (score 0):

How are the problem speakers connected to the computer? Do they only use the standard 1/8" stereo audio output jack from the audio interface, or are they also connected via usb, as some speakers are? Same question about the speakers that don't cause this problem? Do the problem speakers also manifest this issue on another machine with a similar setup and use case scenario? Is this in reference to the "official" smartboard speakers from Smarttech?

Comment: They are connected through the same USB extender.  The Speaker that is working is an internal speaker in the computer.  The speakers having an issue are the official SmartBoard speakers, yes.

This was not an issue on the computers that were in there previously, although it did manifest briefly in a different room with the same setup when I replaced the computer, although it didn't persist in there like it does in this particular room.